# Compare two multiple strings with comma seperated and make it bold

Tags: php, laravel

I have two strings
$string1 = "php developer,developer, sql developer";
$string2 = "developer, android developer,php developer";
I want to match string1 with string2. Any characters in string1 matching with string2, I want to make it bold
The result will be like
"**developer**, andriod **developer**,**php developer**"
Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? thanks

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is a "requirements dump".  In other words, you have expressed your requirements and shown absolutely no evidence of research or toil.  The volunteers here are often paid professionals; they are not here to do your work for free.

Comment: Your [mcve] includes some ambiguity (whether you know it or not) regarding if you want to honor word boundaries or if substrings within whole words should be made bold.  We also don't know if you need case-insensitivity.

Comment: Yes, i need case insensitive Mick. Actually i didn't mentioned my code which I have tried.

Comment: I noticed.  You are welcome to complete your question by [edit]ing it.  Now that I have shown you a duplicate (and there are many more duplicates on this topic), your question cannot be reopened until you have proven that the duplicate is unsuitable.  Then again, it probably won't be reopened because it is a duplicate of many pages on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear for me. You say in your description that you want to make bold **any character** (so, android should has bold in the **d** ans the **o** as those letters are present in `developer`), but in your example you just make bold any word that is present as a keyword.

If you want to highlight the characters, do this:

```php
<?php
$string1 = "php developer,developer, sql developer"; 
$string2 = "developer, android developer,php developer";

$chars = array_unique (str_split($string1));
foreach ($chars as $char) {
    $string2 = str_replace($char, '<b>'.$char.'</b>', $string2);
}
echo $string2;
```

If you want to highlight the words that are present as a keyword, do this:

```
<?php

$string1 = "php developer,developer, sql developer"; 
$string2 = "developer, android developer,php developer";

$keywords = array_unique (preg_split('/\s|,/', $string1));
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $string2 = str_replace($keyword, '<b>'.$keyword.'</b>', $string2);
}
echo $string2;
```

Comment: Hiee @kenny, thanks for the reply, My requirement is any word matching in string with string2 , i need to make it bold. In the above example, which you mentioned, every first word is getting bold, but i want any word that is matching..i want to make it bold

Comment: Then the second snippet of my answer solves your requirement.

Comment: `str_split()` are you splitting on each character?!?

Comment: Hiee @KennyLajara your second snippet working fine. I also want case insensitive condition for it. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code

```
$string1 = "php developer,developer, sql developer";
$string2 = "developer, android developer,php developer";

$newString1 = \Str::of($string1)->replace(',', ' ')->explode(' ')->filter()->unique();

foreach ($newString1 as $key => $value) {
    $string2 = \Str::of($string2)->replace($value, "<b>{$value}</b>");
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  We do not aim to be a snippet dumping ground.  Stack Overflow wants to be a resource that empowers and educates thousands of future researchers.  Please find the [edit] and use plain English to improve this answer.